# Using and retrieving PHP variables within JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I've just started using JSON to throw around information between pages and I simply can't figure this one out.

Basically, I have one page that's using jquery getJSON to get some JSON data from another page. But the PHP variables won't/can't get replaced with the necessary content.

Here's the jquery script (which is working fine I believe)

```
$.getJSON("./menu-controller.php", { editId: getEditId, getEditInfo: true },function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var id = data.itemId;
    alert(id);
});
```

I can get it to work just fine when using this code on the other page

```
$json = '{ "itemId":"4" }';
echo $json;
```

HOWEVER, if I use this, then it won't work

```
$menuId = 4;
$json = '{ "itemId":$menuId }';
echo $json;
```

So my question is, how can I get $menuId to actually replace itself with the number and come back on the other page correctly?

I've tried messing with the quotes and re-arranging the quotes for 4 hours. It either comes up with an error or it doesn't replace $menuId with the actual number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, PHP variables are interpolated in double quotes only and not in single quotes. So, you've to do something like this:

```
    $json = "{ \"itemId\":$menuId }";
    echo $json;
```

Please see the demonstration over here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/CDC0oM

Comment: You should **NOT** build JSON strings by hand.

Comment: @RainFromHeaven: Agree, but this answer is relative to what have been asked in the question. I am sure that he should be knowing that the PHP variables are interpolated in double-quoted strings only, afterwards.

Comment: Sometimes, through no fault of their own, people ask the wrong questions. It's better to answer the question they should have asked that will ultimately be more helpful, imo.

Answer (score 4):

You should make a PHP array instead and then convert it to JSON.

For instance:

```
$array = array();
$array['itemId'] = $menuId;
echo json_encode($array);
```

Note: there is also a `json_decode` function that takes in a JSON string and converts it into PHP as well. You might find that useful.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because it recommends using `json_encode` to build JSON strings.

Answer (score 1):

In this sample:

```
$menuId = 4;
$json = '{ "itemId":$menuId }';
echo $json;
```

You have wrapped your JSON string in single quotes. PHP substitutes values in **double** quotes, so the value is not substituted here, and the vale you echo is

```
{ "itemId":$menuid }  - this is not valid JSON.
```

You're better off creating a PHP array and using `json_encode()` to create the SON string:

```
echo json_encode(array("itemId"=>$menuId));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've enclosed your PHP variable within single (rather than double) quotes, so PHP isn't looking in the string for variables to replace.

So this should work:

```
$json = "{ \"itemId\": $menuId}";
```

As well as the json_encode method suggested by Cezary Wojcik (which is going to be a lot more flexible if the data gets more complex!).

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the help and example! I got it working.

Comment: You should **NOT** build JSON strings by hand.

Comment: @RainFromHeaven Which is why I suggest Cezary Wojcik's answer as being the correct one, whilst still pointing out what was wrong with the code in the question.